# Sum up into a new column from a range of values of a column in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below

```
articles
10
99
101
101
10005
1000001
1000001
```

I want the output dataframe as below

```
range              sum
1-100              109
101-10000          202
10001-1000000      10005
1000001-100000000  2000002
...                ...
```

How to achieve this. I am new to spark and scala.

Comment: The logic behind your sum isn't clear. What does the range represent ? It's the sum of what ?

Comment: @eliasah - by 'range' i am meaning range of the articles column. 1-100 in this range two rows are there 10 and 99 and their sum is 109

Comment: Ok. Have you tried anything ? I suggest that you first find the ranges your value are in and then group by range and sum on articles

Comment: I have not tried any. Can you help me out there?

Comment: I gave you a suggestion.

Comment: code snippet will help more. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest that you first find the ranges of your values using `when`/`otherwise` then you can group by that `range` and perform a `sum` aggregation on `articles` :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("range", 
          when($"articles" >  0 and $"articles" <= 100, lit("1-100"))
            .otherwise(
              when($"articles" > 100 and $"articles" <= 10000, lit("101-10000")).otherwise(lit("others"))
            )
         ).groupBy("range").agg(sum($"articles")).orderBy("range").show

// +---------+-------------+
// |    range|sum(articles)|
// +---------+-------------+
// |    1-100|          109|
// |101-10000|          202|
// |   others|      2010007|
// +---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use an UDF to categorize (bucketize) the articles, then using plain `groupBy().agg()` to calculate the sum.

```
case class Bucket(start: Long, end: Long) {
  def contains(l: Long) = start <= l && end >= l
  override def toString: String = s"$start - $end"
}

val buckets = Seq(
  Bucket(1L, 100L),
  Bucket(101L, 10000L),
  Bucket(10001L, 100000L),
  Bucket(1000001L, 10000000L)
)

val bucketize = udf((l: Long) => buckets.find(_.contains(l)).map(_.toString))

df
  .withColumn("bucket", bucketize($"article"))
  .groupBy($"bucket")
  .agg(
    sum($"article").as("sum")
  )
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `groupByKey` method on a `Dataset` to easily define your keying instead of grouping by a single column value as you would normally do with `groupBy`. The following examples can be run on your `spark-shell`, otherwise remember to create your `SparkSession` and `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum`:

```
// relevant types: one for actual data, the other to define ranges
final case class Data(articles: Int)
final case class Range(from: Int, to: Int)

// the data we want to process
val dataset = spark.createDataset(
  Seq(Data(10), Data(99), Data(101), Data(101), Data(10005), Data(1000001), Data(1000001)))

// the ranges we wanto _bucket_ our data in
val ranges = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(
  Seq(Range(1, 100), Range(101, 10000), Range(10001, 1000000), Range(1000001, 100000000)))

// the actual operation: group by range and sum the values in each bucket
dataset.groupByKey {
  d =>
    ranges.value.find(r => d.articles >= r.from && d.articles <= r.to).orNull
}.agg(sum("articles").as[Long])
```

This would be the output of this snippet of code:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
|                key|sum(articles)|
+-------------------+-------------+
|            [1,100]|          109|
|        [101,10000]|          202|
|    [10001,1000000]|        10005|
|[1000001,100000000]|      2000002|
+-------------------+-------------+
```

What we have done:

- define and broadcast a set of ranges you want to key your values by
- use the broadcast set of ranges to *bucket* the data into the ranges
- `sum` by `articles` and cast the result to `Long` (required for typed `Dataset`s)

Data that don't fall into a specific bucket will be grouped into a row with `null` range.

Please not that I used the word *bucket* to convey the meaning of grouping by a range, but this has not connection to Hive bucketing (which you may hear a lot when trying to optimize joins on Spark).